# Why can't I scan the batgirl suit as a solution to Riddler's riddle?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

This is on PC, the Steam version of Batman: Arkham Knight.

I'm trying to solve the first Riddler's puzzle on Bleake Island, the solution to which is the Batgirl suit in the Clock tower as I understand. I've used the remote hacking device to open the closet.

[image: why u not solve]

I've opened the secret closet and I can see the Batgirl suit, but I don't know how to "solve" the riddle. I've tried going into Detective mode or zooming in, but the riddle isn't solved as shown in the [video here](https://youtu.be/6JN0vSWD890?t=79).

I've tried exiting the game and restarting, and I've solved all the other main storylines

[image: I hate you riddler]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I had to press and **hold** the scan key (X in my controls) to scan it, not just press X once ‍♂️