# At Bleake Island, how do I destroy a breakable wall that is above me, so that I could get to a Riddler Trophy?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

In *Batman: Arkham Knight* on PS4, I'm at Bleake Island and can't get to a Riddler Trophy because of a wall, I can't use the Batmobile because it's blocked by buildings. Any ideas?

Comment: Btw this is my 60th Riddle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I scan the batgirl suit as a solution to Riddler's riddle?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/400309/why-cant-i-scan-the-batgirl-suit-as-a-solution-to-riddlers-riddle)

Comment: @l3l_aze I will assume "wall" wasn't a description of a glass window, so VTLO :)

Comment: It's a  , There's no way to use the Exploding gel from what I can see

Comment: Cheese Hitman - Have you tried to do so? It was possible to do so on Arkham City when the ceiling is close enough. @Joachim - What's VTOL? With so many people who aren't native English speakers I just took a shot at it being different terminology for the same thing, lol.

Comment: @l3l_aze VTLO = Vote To Leave Open (VTOL is Vertical Take-Off and Landing, which is unrelated :) And the answer in the suggested duplicate is to hold the scan button, not breaking through the wall.

Comment: Well I would do the ceiling strat but... There's no ceiling.

Comment: @Joachim it's a riddler Trophy, all that would do is add it's location to the map.

Comment: Also Happy New years Eve 